# capturing states between tags in python using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, lxml.html

I want to capture the word **`WORD`** sentence **`This is what I want.`** in following format:

```
<div id="message1">
<div class="message2">
<strong>WORD</strong> This is what I want.<br/>
</div>              
</div>
```

What I tried is:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
cont=session.get('http://mywebsite.com').content
tree=html.fromstring(cont)
word=tree.xpath('//div[@class="message2"]/strong')
sentence=tree.xpath('//div[@class="message2"]/br')
print word
print sentence
```

Nothing is printed for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find [xpath helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en) is great for solving problems like this one

```
word = tree.xpath('//div[@class="message2"]/strong/text()')[0]
sentence = tree.xpath('//div[@class="message2"]/strong/following-sibling::text()[1]')[0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why he would phrase the question as this is what I want, but say what he want's is the single word in the strong tag?  so if that is what he's looking for, than your answer is correct.

Comment: that answer was actually wrong... Either way, I fixed it now :)

Comment: it is still wrong :) While array indexes start at 1 in xpath, they still start at `0` in python.

Comment: Yes This is correct when I test it in interactive python. but when I want to capture urls source and parse it nothing is printed. why?

Comment: It should work, can you test my code (which is using the `0` as offset)?

Comment: oh, I see, your answer uses the offset outside of xpath, mine is in the xpath. Offsets in xpath are one based, so the answer should be the same

Comment: @MortezaLSC with this code and hek2mgl I get the expected output. What are you getting? Nothing?

Comment: Can you maybe send us a link of the actual data you are parsing, it could be that there is a discrepancy

Comment: When I use:`sentence=tree.xpath('//*[@id="message1"]/text()')` the result is: `['\n\n \n\n\n \n ']`

Comment: Try the xml helper plugin for chrome. It helps a lot, then at least you can see realtime what is being selected and why

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want :)

```
from lxml import html

text = """ 
<div id="message1">
<div class="message2">
<strong>WORD</strong> This is what I want.<br/>
</div>              
</div>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(text);
print(tree.xpath("//div[@class='message2']/strong/following-sibling::text()")[0])
```

Comment: very good. but when I want to capture real url source and parse the error would be: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What do you mean with *real* source? If you get that error, it means there are `message2` elements in the HTML which don't contain text at this place.

Comment: I mean `real url web page` not text='''...'''

Comment: when I remove part `[0]` it doesn't show me anything

Comment: Why should it? However, the question starts to get a bit weird. If you are now experiencing other problems which are not related to the code you showed in the question, it gets hard to answer. I could just give a guess.

Comment: In code as I say in question: `cont=session.get('http://mywebsite.com').content
tree=html.fromstring(cont)` and when I use your xpath pattern doen't show me the result :(

Comment: Note that `http://mywebsite.com` doesn't exist. **Should I guess the content of that page?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure specific about LXML but if that is the text you're looking for, calling text will not return the child tree text which exists inside of the strong tag.

So in general XPath terms, this is what you're looking for to only match that text.

```
//*[@class="message2"]/text()
```